Resource protection for static webpages
I'm new to web developement so I'm sorry in advance because I assume this is a pretty simple question.
I'm currently hosting a website on hostinger - deployed straight from my github repo.
Currently, someone is able to type files directly in the url
e.g. https://mywebsite.com/index.css to see the css in that file being used or https://mywebsite.com/script.js to see the js code in that file
Is this a problem? I assume it is as other websites prevent this from happening by either redirecting at that url or just returning a 403 error.
If it is a problem, how would I go about doing the same?

The browser must have access to the styles and scripts to work. But depending on how the website is deployed from Git, browsers may have access to the .git folder and all your project history, including stuff that you "deleted". That could be more of a problem. How to block that directory depends on the server. E.g. Apache would use a .htaccess file for this configuration.

On Stackoverflow: How to secure css and js files means end user could not download our css and js file? from 2013. Got essentially the same answer as it was given here,

reminds me of jeffk

This is not a problem, it's how the web has worked since forever. Some people use obfuscation in a misguided attempt to protect their intellectual property, but that's rare and probably ineffectual (if there's value in de-obfuscating, somebody will take the time to do so). The vast majority of CSS and JS out there is also not original in any interesting sense of the word, so chances are good that nobody is ever going to look at it raw.
One exception is if someone does something really bad and starts trusting the client to run whatever they send to it. Back in the early days of the web it was fairly common to find JS code which included secrets which should never be sent to the client, for example, or to use client side code to protect the server.

It is ok to use client side code to protect the server from honest well meaning idiots. Not a good strategy against malicious 12 year olds that you can’t trial as an adult.

Or malicious 21-year-olds that you can't track down, arrest, and trial as an adult. Or shadowy cartels and state actors that are protected by their own private armies, international treaties, or nuclear weapons.

Or just automated scripts trawling the web every second of every day to find a way in and mine crypto.
